# Retrieve record-Id of html data POST to CRM

Tags: php, xml, forms, php-curl, zoho

Part of my html form's action is the following:

- the form data is posted to a CRM (Zoho) via php Curl, where a new contact is created

When the data is successfully inserted and the contact is created, my browser returns the following response:

*Record(s) added successfully34425260000003590072018-08-24 14:44:482018-08-24 14:44:48 1*

Amon other things, the response echoes the contact's recordId (an 18 digit number): *3442526000000359007*

Subsequently, I want to execute the following action:

- upload a .docx file to the newly created contact

I have code, which uses php Curl as well, which is able to upload files to specific contacts based on their record-Ids, however there is one flaw. Each time a new contact is created, a unique record-Id is assigned to that contact by the CRM.

I can't figure out how to modify my code so that it fetches the record-Id of the newly created contact (which can be used to upload the file to the correct contact (based on its record-Id) upon execution).

This is the piece of code that uploads the file to the contact:

```
<?php
    $recordId = "3442526000000328222";
    $auth   = "abcdefghijklmnopQRSTU";
    $module = "Contacts";
    $file_name="./../kundenanfragen/'.$firstname.' '.$lastname.'.docx";
    $theurl = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/$module/uploadFile?authtoken=$auth&scope=crmapi";
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$theurl);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    $post=array("id"=>$recordId,"content"=>curl_file_create($file_name,'image/jpeg' , basename( $file_name)));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
    $response=curl_exec($ch);
    /* RESPONSE SHOWN ON PAGE */
    echo "<hr />RESPONSE<pre>"; print_r($response); echo "</pre>";
    curl_close($ch);
```

Before that, the following code posts the html form data and creates the contact:

```
<?php
$auth = "abcdefghijklmnopQRSTU";
$xml = "
    <Contacts>
        <row no=\"1\">
            <FL val=\"First Name\">".$firstname."</FL>
            <FL val=\"Last Name\">".$lastname."</FL>
        </row>
    </Contacts>
";
$result = insert($auth,$xml);
print_r($result);
function insert($auth,$xml)
{
    $curl_url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Contacts/insertRecords?";
    $curl_post_fields = "authtoken=". $auth ."&scope=crmapi&xmlData=". $xml ."";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_fields);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

Do you have any tips on how to retrieve the record-Id when the contact is created?

I read somewhere that the response from when the contact is created (*Record(s) added successfully34425260000003590072018-08-24 14:44:482018-08-24 14:44:48 1*) is stored in an XML file, which can be accessed to extract the record-Id from it and insert it in the *'upload file'* piece of code:

```
$recordId = "Record-Id which was fetched from XML file right here";
```

I didn't find any leads on how to do this.

I would appreciate any tips on how to extract the record-Id. If you can point into a good direction, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I noticed that nobody commented so far. Just so you know: I don't need a solution, I only need a hint, so that I can go look for a solution myself. Right now Idk where to look.

Comment: I suggest you for use zoho api verssion 2. it return json data from zoho. And easy to find information from there.